# Есть ли базы данных, которые не работают с SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Существуют ли базы данных, в которых нет SQL? Ну, например, которые по какой-то другой схеме и с другими языками работают? Что это за базы, если существуют?

Comment: MongoDB, ну и вообще гугли NoSQL

Comment: Есть "вид бд" - SQL -эти бд именно для работы на языке SQL(реляционные). Есть NoSql (нереляционные базы данных) - видимо то что вам нужно.

Comment: Ну, формально хранение данных в простых текстовых файлах тоже NoSQL :D

Comment: Википедия: "База данных", все кроме реляционных это не SQL, среди реляционных то же могут быть не SQL.

Comment: Автор имеет ввиду не принцип работы, а язык запросов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существуют, конечно.

- `Key-value` СУБД (а они всё-таки тоже базы данных) со своими протоколами. `Memcache` и `Redis` к примеру
- встраиваемые библиотеки предлагающие только прямой API интерфейс. Мне вспоминаются только `sqlite` - но он SQL, да `berkeley db` - а этот `key-value`. Ну вот [`InfinityDB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfinityDB) нашёл в пример для Java
- множество модных `NoSQL` как правило не используют SQL. Например, упомянутое `mongodb` использует язык запроса базирующийся на `JSON` структуре.
- язык [`Datalog`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog), к примеру, который вполне повлиял на добавление в SQL рекурсивных запросов
- какие-то субд могут поддерживать и SQL и какой-то другой протокол. Например, вы можете взаимодействовать с `MySQL` без использования SQL - через [`HandlerSocket`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/handlersocket.html). При том, SQL может быть как основным языком для СУБД, так и альтернативным, иногда предлагающим меньше возможностей, но добавленным для совместимости.

Реляционные базы данных сейчас практически все с SQL. Но очевидно есть студенческие и академические эксперименты, которые SQL делать не стали. Некоторые из них может быть даже развиваются, но чего-то известного найти не удалось. По не реляционным базам разброс куда шире.

Отдельный интересный вопрос - что именно считать SQL. СУБД может предоставлять язык запросов, лишь на первый взгляд похожий на SQL, без поддержки большого числа возможностей и поведения стандарта SQL, а с какими-то своими решениями.

Comment: перечисление каким то слабеньким выглядит. как будто есть key-val, реляционные и noSQL. Например ADABAS не принято относить к noSQL, но она и не SQL да еще и не совсем реляционная (хотя так выглядит). Боюсь правильное перечисление будет состоять из сотни пунктов :)

Comment: @Mike , согласен. Но настроения гуглить и писать ещё простыню текста как-то нет.

Answer (score 5):

SQL это детище т.н. строгой математической [теории реляционной алгебры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0), на основе которой были созданы реляционные СУБД, которые используют SQL.

Если вкратце суть реляционной теории состоит в том, что множество данных это таблицы, в которых определены операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления. Результатом этих операций всегда является таблица (отношение в терминах реляционной теории множеств). Язык SQL, собственно говоря, и определяет порядок и синтаксис выполнения операций сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления.

До создания реляционных СУБД существовали (да и сейчас существуют) СУБД построенные на других принципах - основные из которых это:

1. Иерархические СУБД, построенные на основе [иерархической модели данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)
2. Сетевые СУБД, построенные на основе [сетевой структуры данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Такие СУБД в основном работали на древних мейнфреймах типа [IBM System/360](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360) - я еще застал те времена, и в свое время немного потрудился на них.

Нынешние новомодные NoSQL в общем-то являются инкарнацией старых (в основном сетевых) СУБД, так что новое - это хорошо забытое старое.